# Reading static HTML content from Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I added a tab with static HTML content to my facebook page. It is a simple form with couple of input fields and a submit button. Does FB store this form data anywhere? Is there any way to read this data using graph API/FQL? I know that we can easily access it using Javascript right away but I want to access this data at a later point of time using HTTP calls.

Regards,
Robert